# Add contact using contact app to a non google account

Tags: android

While adding a contact from contact app(default) we have a account picker dialog in which we see that (SIM 1,SIM 2,gmail account).

**MY QUESTION IS** : I want to add a contact in my custom contact provider using contact app but there is no option to do that because when I click on the add button of contact app I get only these options(SIM 1,SIM 2,gmail account),
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to enable some configuration in xml file.
You can use below link to get help what you have to do 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.3_r1/packages/apps/Contacts/tests/res/xml/test_basic_contacts.xml

Comment: Thanks buddy !! :)